# undefined function base_url()

Tags: php, codeigniter

Why is this line not working in `constants.php` :-

`define('FILE_UPLOAD_VIRTUAL_DIR',  base_url() . '/uploads/');`

`base_url()` works in all views. Then why not in constants.php?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because `constants.php` is included before the library defining `base_url()` is.

I don't know CI, but look if there is any chance to define the constant at a later point in the program flow. A CI expert may be able to tell you in more detail where exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
define('FILE_UPLOAD_VIRTUAL_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/');
```

if you want to define path to file upload directory you don't need url you need path.

Comment: Be aware that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` won't give you the same result as `base_url()` (defined in application's config.php) !

Comment: Yup, this is not clean practice. When building a CI app, use CI's functions.